# Use variable in regex in Groovy script

Tags: groovy, soapui

I use following `Groovy` script in `SoapUI` to check size and extension of file.

```
def ext = context.expand('${Properties#D_file_ext}')

dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) {file ->
    if(file.length() > 0 && file.name =~/\.$\{ext\}/){
            list << file
    }
}
```

I have an 5 kB xml file in root folder, but script is unable to find it.

Comment: What is the value of "${Properties#D_file_ext}". A file name with a relative path, absolute path, or no path at all but just the filename...?

Comment: @Steen : It contains just an extension, like pdf.

Comment: Ahhh. Too fast on that one. Sorry. I think the $\{ext} is the root of your problem. I don't think that will translate into the variable content.

Comment: Could this be a solution for you ? http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Using-a-variable-in-Regular-Expression-td370146.html

Comment: @Steen : That format is OK.